# Repartition HDD to give Ubuntu more space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive, gparted

My Laptop came installed with Windows 7 and 320 GB of hard drive space.  A few weeks ago I decided to try Ubuntu for a change, and created a 30GB partition for it.

Now, I want to give more space for the Ubuntu partition because I want to use Ubuntu OS permanently and probably migrate completely sometime soon from W7.  I tried GParted Editor but I can't resize/move partitons (I see a lock icon next to partitions).

How do I resize the W7 partition FROM Ubuntu? Is it possible? Can I "unmount" the W7 partition and then resize it without breaking it?

Comment: Try booting from the CD, and do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT try resizing Windows 7 drive from GParted. It creates huge issues with boot sector and flags, and you might as well just reinstall Windows. Just shrink the Windows volume from Windows `Disk Management` in `Adminstrative Tools`. That will give you free space. After that downoad GParted Live, here `http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.14.1-6/gparted-live-0.14.1-6-i486.iso/download` burn it to a CD and boot from it, then use the freed disk space after shrinking Windows drive to resize Ubuntu drive. Make sure you're resizing the `/` and not `/home` or `/usr` if you have flags for them.